# When using officedown changing from portait to landscape causes problems with page numbering

Tags: officer, officedown

I have been using officeR and officedown a lot in the past months. These are great packages sparing me a lot of time and effort, since many of my collaborators want *.docx files.
However, I have one problem which can be reproduced using the bookdown example included in the package. After installing the packages you need to run:

```
dir <- system.file(package = "officedown", "examples", "bookdown")
file.copy(dir, getwd(), recursive = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE)
rmarkdown::render_site("bookdown")
browseURL("bookdown/_book/bookdown.docx")
```

The resulting word document shows all the possibilities of officedown. However, you see a word document with 10 pages. Word “says” that there are 11 pages. After inserting page numbers using the MS word function, you see that in the bookdown-example page 5 is in portrait and then the next page (landscape ) has the number 7. Page 6 seems to be missing. If you print or convert the file in pdf, there is now an (empty) page 6 . I have faced the problem always and only when I included pages in landscape using “<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START---> “ and “ <!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP---> “. A change from landscape back to portrait does not seem to cause problems.

Any ideas to solve this?

Best wishes

Jörg

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is related to `BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START` because my current documents do not run into this error. I think it might be related to how you are producing your document.

Is there a reason you are using these 2 lines?

```
rmarkdown::render_site("bookdown")
browseURL("bookdown/_book/bookdown.docx")
```

Assuming you have `officedown` installed try the following steps

[image: img]

[image: img]

When rendered using the `knit` button (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`K`), it does not produce the extra page you describe.